# How to multiply a NxN matrix H with a Nx1 array t = [t1,t2,...,tN] such that H*t = [H*t1,H*t2,...,H*tN] using numpy?

Tags: numpy, matrix

I know how to do this with for loops, but is there a way to use numpy arrays and their operations to achieve this type of multiplication?

Comment: Are you asking for an `NxNxN` matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.multiply.outer`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> H = np.arange(9).reshape(3, 3)
>>> t = np.c_[10:40:10]
>>> 
>>> H                                                                                                               
array([[0, 1, 2],                                                                                                   
       [3, 4, 5],                                                                                                   
       [6, 7, 8]])                                                                                                  
>>> t                                                                                                               
array([[10],                                                                                                        
       [20],                                                                                                        
       [30]])                                                                                                       
>>>                                                                                                                 
>>> np.multiply.outer(t.ravel(), H)
array([[[  0,  10,  20],                                                                                            
        [ 30,  40,  50],                                                                                            
        [ 60,  70,  80]],                                                                                           

       [[  0,  20,  40],                                                                                            
        [ 60,  80, 100],                                                                                            
        [120, 140, 160]],                                                                                           

       [[  0,  30,  60],                                                                                            
        [ 90, 120, 150],                                                                                            
        [180, 210, 240]]])
```